# How to get Query Params from URL in React

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router-dom, query-string

I tried to get query Params from URL by following react router dom documentation in such a way in version 6

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let params = serializeFormQuery(event.target);
    setSearchParams(params);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* ... */}</form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but it returned me empty object

I tried other method as

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link, useLocation, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
function User({ name }) {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

function useQuerym2() {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  return React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
}

function QueryScreen() {
  let query = useQuery();
 let querym2 = useQuerym2();

return <></>
}
```

but got same result

finally I develop a method to get queryParams from URL

```
const convertQueryParamsStringToQueryParamsObject = (string) => {
    let queryParams = {};
    // remove first letter from query string
    string = string.substring(1);
    // console.log("string", string);
    // convert string to array
    const queryParamsArray = string.split("&");
    // console.log("queryParamsArray", queryParamsArray);

    // covert each index query to object
    queryParamsArray.forEach((queryParam) => {
        // console.log("queryParam", queryParam);
        // split param by =
        const queryParamArray = queryParam.split("=");
        // console.log("queryParamArray", queryParamArray);
        queryParams[queryParamArray[0]] = queryParamArray[1];
        // console.log("queryParams", queryParams);
    });
    return queryParams;
};
```

you have to call it in your react function component
like

```
const FunchionalComponent =()=> {

    const { search } = useLocation();
    let queryParams = convertQueryParamsStringToQueryParamsObject(search);
    console.log("queryParams", queryParams);

    return <></>;
};
```

Comment: The first method/example is the `react-router-dom@6` method. The second method/example is the `react-router-dom@5` method. The third seems to be some sort of home-rolled implementation. What exactly is the question here? What is the issue? What do you mean by "but it returned me empty object"? What exactly is being returned, and where, that you are expecting? This post needs some improvement.

Answer (score 3):

In you second method this was missing

```
function useQuery() {
  // Use get method to retrieve queryParam
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search).get("queryParamName");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `searchParams` here *looks* like an empty object if you log it to the console but in fact it's a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object. You need to call the [get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) method on that object with the name of the parameter to get its value:

```
// https://example.com/products?page=10

const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

searchParams.get('page'); // 10
```